# how to show chart in asp.net with two tables with same column names but with different values in it C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am stucked in one problem, please help me. so what I want is to show chart with database.

I have two tables with same column names but different values in those tables.

**First Table**

```
Standard Table

| Min_Moist  |   Min_Temp   |
-----------------------------    
|   20.14    |     41.2     |
```

**Second Table**

```
Current Table

|  Min_Moist  |   Min_Temp  | 
-----------------------------
|    85.0     |    45.10    |
```

So what I want is to show these two standard and current values in chart..

Please guide me how can I show these values together and chart should be displayed when user selects the values from a drop down list.. According to the drop down list value, the table column values should be chosen.

Comment: Are you having problem selecting the data from the tables or showing the data on the chart or both? Which charting library are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying Lukazoid !! i need to show a chart in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can have select values from both tables with `UNION` like:

```
SELECT
  Min_Moist  
  ,Min_Temp 
  , 1 AS CurrentTable
FROM CURRENTTABLE 
  WHERE <your condition here>

UNION

SELECT
  Min_Moist  
  ,Min_Temp 
  ,0 AS CurrentTable
FROM StandardTable
  WHERE <your condition here>
```

Here I also added a flag column named `CurrentTable` to determine whether data is coming from `CurrentTable` or `StandardTable`

Hope it helps.